# How to checkout a branch by a name pattern in a Windows batch?

Tags: git, batch-file

I'd like to locally checkout a branch automatically from a Windows batch file looking for a given branch name pattern, for example `rc_` so I would checkout the latest release candidate without bothering to check which one is the latest.

if I have (note the use of prune to make sure I have the latest view on origin and not all outdated branches):

```
> git fetch --all --prune 
> git branch --all 
* master
remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
remotes/origin/branch1
remotes/origin/branch2
remotes/origin/branch3
remotes/origin/rc_1.1.1
```

I'd like to automatically checkout `rc_1.1.1`; I'd do the following from a Windows bat file (but doesn't work):

```
git branch --list --all | for /f "tokens=1" %%i in ('findstr \/rc_') do set my_rc_branch=%%i
git checkout %my_rc_branch%
```

I have two problems here:

1. the `...do set my_rc_branch=%%i` isn't working because it is always empty in the following step
2. I need to checkout only `rc_1.1.1` and not `remotes/origin/rc_1.1.1`, how can I get only the `rc_1.1.1` part into `my_rc_branch`?

Comment: What if there are multiple branches beginning with `rc_`? What's the expected behaviour? Take the first? The most recent?

Comment: @RomainValeri thanks a lot! good point, I'd like the latest and this is somewhat ensured by the prune step but if there is a more streamlined way to get the latest semantic versioning value then I would have a much more robust solution :)

Comment: OK, thanks for the new details. Reworking my answer shortly.

Comment: This is for windows not Linux unfortunately and plan dos bat files :(

Comment: Your command should be within the parentheses, e.g. ```for /f %%i in ('git branch --list --all ^| findstr \/rc_') do set "FirstTokenOfLastMatchingLineOutput=%%i"```. You would then use the variable `%FirstTokenOfLastMatchingLineOutput%` in a subsequent command. To follow on from your previous question, which I've already answered, you probably want to change ```=%%i``` to ```=%%~nxi```.

Comment: I should add, if you want to ensure that you are matching only the leaf, _(last item of the output path)_, as opposed to any instance of `/rc_` anywhere in the branches, you should probably improve your findstr.exe pattern to this too: ```/ir "[/]rc_[^/][^/]*$"```.

Comment: amazing stuff, I will test it ... :) how about writing an answer instead of so many comments?

Comment: I have added a summary of that information to the answer area for you too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your command should be within the parentheses, and to ensure that you are matching only the leaf, (last item of the output path), as opposed to any instance of `/rc_` anywhere in the branches, you should probably improve your findstr.exe pattern too:

```bash
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions
Set "my_rc_branch="
For /F %%G In ('git.exe branch --list --all 2^>NUL ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /ir "[/]rc_[^/][^/]*$"') Do Set "my_rc_branch=%%~nxG"
If Defined my_rc_branch git.exe checkout %my_rc_branch%
```